# How to compute $d X_t$ for given $X_t$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to understans, what would $d X_t$ be, according to the Itô's formula, for the following $X_t$, where $W_t$ is a Wiener process:

$$
X_t = f(W_t, t) = 5 + t^2W_t^2 + 5\int\limits_0^tW_u d u + \int\limits_0^tW^2_u d W_u \tag{1}
$$

The problem is that I pretty much understand how Itô's formula works, and I know, that in full form: $X_t = X_0 + \int\limits_0^tf'_w d W_u + \int\limits_0^t(f'_u + \frac{1}{2}f''_{ww}) d u$, but I do not understand how to properly compute $f'_w$ here, precisely, I do not understand how to deal with integral terms in (1). First two terms are easy to differentiate with respect to $w$, but how can I compute the derivative of $\int\limits_0^tW_u d u$ or $\int\limits_0^tW^2_u d W_u$ with respect to $w$ (not $t$)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Itô's formula, $d(W_t^2) = 2W_t dW_t + dt$, so by Itô's product rule we have $$d(t^2 W_t^2) = d(t^2)W_t^2 + t^2 d(W_t^2) + d(t^2) d(W_t^2) = (2t W_t^2 +t^2 )dt + 2W_t t^2dW_t$$

It follows that:
$$X_t = 5 + \int_0^t (5W_u + 2uW_u^2 +u^2 ) du + \int_0^t (W_u^2 + 2W_u u^2 )dW_u$$

from which you can extract $dX_t$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for such an explicit explanation!

Comment: How couldn't have I noticed that earlier.. Well, I have just found out that I computed $dX_t$ already like 3 days ago, and the full form of $X_t$ exactly corresponds to yours, thank you once again though!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting confused. There is no $\partial W_t$. If you have for example a scalar SDE with real values, $f$ is just a function $f:\mathbb R \times [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R.$ The partial derivatives are like with any other function. For example, if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f'(x)=2x$, $f''(x)=2$ and the partial derivative with respect to $t$ would be zero.

(I don't have enough reputation to write a comment)

Comment: So, am I then correct, interpreting $\frac{\partial}{\partial W_t}\left(\int\limits_0^tW^2_u\partial u\right)$ as simply zero?

Comment: it doesn't make sense to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial W_t}.$ What does that mean?

Comment: Oh, it seems like I have confused $d$ and $\partial$ here, of course I should be using the total derivative sign. The case is yet that I do not understand how to deal with $\frac{d}{dW_t}(\int\limits_0^t W_u^2du)$.

Comment: The expression "$\frac{d}{dW_u}$" doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Why doesn't it? Well, may I assume that it may be the case we are talking about different things? At least in my stochastic processes course, teacher employs that notation, and the question that I have to solve concerns computation of $dX_t$. Even on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma), as far as I have just seen, they do use $dB_t$ notation whence describing Ito's lemma.

Comment: $dW_t$ is not the same as $\frac{d}{dW_t}$. This last expression doesn't make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132249/discussion-between-o-spectrum-and-sebastian).